# Python-Driven Appium - "Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched!"

Tags: android, python, appium

I'm currently trying to get a test app running in my android virtual device, and I'm fairly certain I've gotten everything set up in my script correctly, but am receiving the following from Appium when I attempt to run it:

> info: [debug] Responding to client with error:
>   {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created.
>   (Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be
>   launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable
>   activity)","origValue":"Activity used to start app doesn't exist or
>   cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable
>   activity"},"sessionId":null}

This is the code that I've written setting up the capabilities for the script:

```
def setUp(self):
    #Setup for the test
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '6.0'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Galaxy S6 API 23'
    desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname("__file__"),'TestApp.apk'))
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.test.test'
    desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.test.test.UnityPlayerActivity'
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

`UnityPlayerActivity` is the only activity present in the .apk, so I imagine it's would be the activity launching the app. Any help is appreciated--thanks!

Comment: could you share the `AndroidManifest.xml` for the app you are testing on

Comment: you can also try with just `desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.UnityPlayerActivity'` if the activity is a surity